# No module named 'azure.storage.blob.sharedaccesssignature'

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been struggling with the Azure library for a while now. I want to use Azure in python. I have `azure.storage.blob` installed (via `pip install azure.storage.blob`). I have upgraded it (also tried uninstalling and reinstalling) to version 12.8.1. I'm currently running python 3.7.6.

In spite of all this, I keep getting

```
from azure.storage.blob.sharedaccesssignature import BlobSharedAccessSignature

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage.blob.sharedaccesssignature'
```

I see the module here: https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.sharedaccesssignature.html

So I'm not sure why it's not recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you running your python code from? It is possible that you installed the library for one version but your IDE (Pycharm or Visual studio) is using a virtual environment or a different version of Python.

Comment: I put `import azure.storage.blob` and `print(azure.storage.blob.__version__)` in the script that is throwing the error, and it shows that the module's version is 12.8.1, so it is installed in the right environment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `BlobSharedAccessSignature` is part of the old version of the SDK ([`azure-storage`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python)) whereas you're working with the newer version of the SDK ([`azure.storage.blob version 12.8.1`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob)).

To generate a shared access signature on a blob, you will need to use [`generate_blob_sas()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#generate-blob-sas-account-name--container-name--blob-name--snapshot-none--account-key-none--user-delegation-key-none--permission-none--expiry-none--start-none--policy-id-none--ip-none----kwargs-) function in the new SDK.